# Use Devise without a password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Is there a way I can tell Devise not to use a password?  I'm using Devise with LDAP so the encrypted password field is a wasted column (the password is stored in the LDAP directory). If I delete the encrypted_password column and then add some dummy accessors on my models

```
def encrypted_password
    ""
end

def encrypted_password=dummy
end
```

I can at least get rid of the column in the database.   However, when I create new users I still have to supply a dummy password

```
User.create(:first_name => "Dummy", :password => "dummyPass1", :password_confirmation => "dummyPass1")
```

Is there a setting somewhere that would make this cleaner?

Answer (score 0):

You can take "database_authenticatable" out of the devise config line in your User model, and drop the encrypted_password field entirely.

Comment: For anyone else who stumbles on this question we couldn't get this to work.  Removing database_authenticable lead to other issues.  We eventually removed Devise from our app (since many of it's features aren't helpful in an LDAP situation).